# The recommended way to copy the contents of one directory into another

Tags: zsh

To copy the contents of one directory into another, I can use the following:

```
cp -Rip source-dir/ ../destination-dir/
```

However, it seems that using the trailing slash at the end of source directory when using `cp` and `mv` commands is somewhat [discouraged](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24925767).

> ### No trailing slash on source directory
>
> You **should not** put a trailing slash on the source directory:
>
> The point is relevant to `cp` - **but also to `mv`**, where it is much **more important**.
>
> I'll cite the warning from the manual - note that it's not found in the man page, but in the info page `info coreutils 'mv invocation'`:
>
> > **Warning**: Avoid specifying a source name with a trailing slash,
> > when it might be a symlink to a directory.  Otherwise, 'mv' may do
> > something very surprising, since its behavior depends on the underlying
> > rename system call.  On a system with a modern Linux-based kernel, it
> > fails with 'errno=ENOTDIR'.  However, on other systems (at least
> > FreeBSD 6.1 and Solaris 10) it silently renames not the symlink but
> > rather the directory referenced by the symlink.

Is it really so? And if the answer is "yes", what is the recommended way to copy the contents of a directory?

Comment: Ah, right. The text you quote applies to `mv` though, not sure what the problem with `cp` might be.

Answer (score 1):

I may be completely missing the aim of the question, but couldn't you just use globbing?

For example: `cp -Rip source_dir/* ../destination_dir`

The `*` after the trailing slash would copy the directory structure recursively without copying the directory itself.

```
❯ lt *_dir

destination_dir:


source_dir:

 └──      testdir/
 │  ├────      test_1_1.txt
 │  ├────      test_1_2.txt
 │  └────      test_1_3.txt
 ├──      test_1.txt
 ├──      test_2.txt
 └──      test_3.txt

    Found 7 items in total.

    Folders         : 1
    Recognized files    : 6
    Unrecognized files  : 0

❯ cp -Rip source_dir/* destination_dir
❯ lt *_dir

destination_dir:

 └──      testdir/
 │  ├────      test_1_1.txt
 │  ├────      test_1_2.txt
 │  └────      test_1_3.txt
 ├──      test_1.txt
 ├──      test_2.txt
 └──      test_3.txt

source_dir:

 └──      testdir/
 │  ├────      test_1_1.txt
 │  ├────      test_1_2.txt
 │  └────      test_1_3.txt
 ├──      test_1.txt
 ├──      test_2.txt
 └──      test_3.txt

    Found 14 items in total.

    Folders         : 2
    Recognized files    : 12
    Unrecognized files  : 0
```

Comment: Globbing with `*` will not match `source_dir/.hidden`.